# Find min date from multiple fields in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

Hello I am trying to find min date value between multiple columns in ssrs.

For example If date value in  column A is less then in column B and column B is not nothing and column A is less then column  C and column C is not nothing then chose field A

```
If Not Isnothing(A) and Not Isnothing(B) and A<B and A<C then
A
else if Not Isnothing(B) and Not Isnothing(C) and b<A and B<C
B
...
end if
```

I will be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question recently that had a similar answer here..

[How to set dynamic axis unit in SSRS Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653638/how-to-set-dynamic-axis-unit-in-ssrs-reports/65656019)?

However, if possible I would so this in your dataset query it will be much easier as you can simply do..

```
SELECT MIN(myField) FROM 
   (SELECT A as myField FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT B FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT C FROM myTable
   ) x
```